# Prevent input when text fills visible length of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have an html input that is absolutely positioned over a canvas element. The width is set to meet the right border of a canvas element in the background (highlighted).

[image]

The input is actually appended to the larger canvas element, based on where the user drops the green circle to the left of the input:

`var input = jQuery('<div><input id="edit-annotation-input" ' +
          'style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top:' + (this.textPosition.y - 9) + 'px; left:'+ (this.textPosition.x + 8) +'px; width: ' +  (610 - 7 - this.textPosition.x) + 'px; border: none; color: #0bac3a; outline: none; background-color: transparent !important; padding: 0px; font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt; " ' +
          'spellcheck="false" type="text" name="mytext[]" value="'+string+'"/></div>');
jQuery("div #pad").append(input);`

How can I prevent user input when the text fills the visible width of the input. The text should be stopped in the following example, when the user enters another key the input should be prevented:

[image]"dsadss"

I want to avoid the text cursor just moving along as more input is entered i.e like this which is the default behavior:

[image]
"dsadsssss"

---

I have previously considered using properties such as `maxlength` and the `oninput` event but could not come up with any combination that had this desired effect

Comment: is the width of the input dynamic?  why didn't maxlength work for you?  please include your markup

Comment: @billynoah Yes it is dynamic. I have edited in (sorry for formatting I couldn't get it quite right yet)

Comment: You should create snippet so we can see the problem in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a example hope it will help you or you can refer to it to help your problem.

```js
$("input[name=testInput]").on('keydown keyup',function(event){ 
   var $that = $(this);
   var widthOfInput = getWidthOfInput(document.getElementById("testInput")) ;
   var cssWidth = $that.width();
   //console.log('widthOfInput'+ widthOfInput);
   //console.log('widthInputCss'+ widthInputCss);
   
   // accept key backspace
   var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; 
   if( key == 8 || key == 46 ){
        return true;
   } 
   
   // check limit input
   if(cssWidth < widthOfInput){
      event.preventDefault();
   }
       
});


function getWidthOfInput(inputEl) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("span");
  tmp.className = "input-element tmp-element";
  tmp.innerHTML = inputEl.value.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
  document.body.appendChild(tmp);
  var theWidth = tmp.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.body.removeChild(tmp);
  return theWidth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="testInput" name="testInput" style="width:100px"  />
```

Comment: A slightly modified form of this answer got the job done. The only thing I had to do was make the font size and family of the temporary element the same as the one I was trying to measure the text inside the input of to make the comparison work.